# How solve Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.util.concurrent.GenericFutureListener?

Tags: java, prometheus

yeserday in first time I did try to make Prometheus Client by Java (did begin from Python, last did is GoLang).

Did find Example

```
import io.prometheus.client.Counter;
import io.prometheus.client.Gauge;
import io.prometheus.client.Histogram;
import io.prometheus.client.Summary;
import io.prometheus.client.vertx.MetricsHandler;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;
//import io.prometheus.client.vertx.MetricsHandler;

public class ExampleExporter {

    static final Gauge g = Gauge.build().name("gauge").help("blah").register();
    static final Counter c = Counter.build().name("counter").help("meh").register();
    static final Summary s = Summary.build().name("summary").help("meh").register();
    static final Histogram h = Histogram.build().name("histogram").help("meh").register();
    static final Gauge l = Gauge.build().name("labels").help("blah").labelNames("l").register();

    public static  void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        final Router router = Router.router(vertx);

        router.route("/metrics").handler(new MetricsHandler());

        vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8001);

        g.set(1);
        c.inc(2);
        s.observe(3);
        h.observe(4);
        l.labels("foo").inc(5);
    }



}
```

Did load from Maven Libraries.

After did try run client, did return error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/util/concurrent/GenericFutureListener
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxFactoryImpl.vertx(VertxFactoryImpl.java:30)
    at io.vertx.core.Vertx.vertx(Vertx.java:78)
    at ExampleExporter.main(ExampleExporter.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.util.concurrent.GenericFutureListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 3 more
```

All code and lib did upload
[Git Repository](https://github.com/drno-reg/ExamplePrometheusNode.git)

Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: Sounds like you probably had the library in the classpath when compiling, but probably not when running. How did you try to run it?

Comment: *"How solve Error?"* Add the jar file containing `io.netty.util.concurrent.GenericFutureListener` to the classpath.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you are missing a dependency.  You can get it from

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-all/5.0.0.Alpha2

You can add

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-all -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.Alpha2</version>
</dependency>
```

to your pom file or download the jar from the site and add it to the class path or your lib folder.

Comment: Did return new error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(ILjava/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory;)V
 at io.vertx.core.net.impl.transport.Transport.eventLoopGroup(Transport.java:124)
....

Comment: Try one of the other version https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-all

maybe https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-all/4.1.30.Final

Comment: did try use version 4.1.30.Final - compile without error